# Basic substring search on pattern matching

Tags: postgresql

How do I pull a substring from a column in postgresql basing on a pattern?

```
        RESULTS
        --------------------------------------------
        {"searchtext":"apple","Source":null,"User":null}
        {"searchtext":"banana","Source":null,"User":null}
        {"searchtext":"mango","Source":null,"User":null}
```

the output desired is:

```
        FINAL_RESULT
        --------------------------------------------
        apple
        banana
        mango
```

Here is what I wrote and it is not working:

```
        select substring(af.RESULTS from '{"searchtext":"(.)","Source":null,"User":null}') as FINAL_RESULT from table af;
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was missing '+' character.

```
        select substring(af.RESULTS from '{"searchtext":"(.+)","Source":null,"User":null}') as FINAL_RESULT from table af;
```